# Proof of Cancellation law for type semi-group of a Group action

Tags: graph-theory

In the proof of theorem 8.7 in The "Banach Tarski Paradox" by Stan Wagon, one of the lines stumps me completely.  The bipartite graph that is formed from the second paragraph of the proof on page 115 supposed to be $n$-regular.  But I cannot see it.

Sorry for not retyping the entire theorem/proof in SE, I hope the link is appropriate.

Theorem 8.7

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be the type semigroup of the action of a group $G$ on a set $S$.  If $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{S}$ such that $n\alpha = n\beta$, then $\alpha = beta$.

Proof Screenshot:

http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~schlitt/87proof.png

In particular, given $\overline{b}$, for $j\neq k$, I cannot show that the $a_{1},a_{2}$ such that $\chi(\phi_{m}(a_{1})) = \psi_{j}(b)$ and $\chi(\phi_{n}(a_{2})) = \psi_{k}(b)$ are indeed distinct.

This is of course needed to ensure that there are indeed $n$ edges touching $\overline{b}$.

Comment: That link does not display for me.

Comment: @vadim123 +1 "You have either reached a page that is unavailable for viewing ..."

Comment: My apologies, I will find a way to fix this shortly.  Thank you for looking all the same.  Update: Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you agree that there are $n$ edges emanating from $\overline a$ by means of $\chi$ and the$\phi_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ and that they end in $n$ different $\overline b$'s.

By the same argument, using $\chi^{-1}$ and the $\psi_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, you can construct $n$ edges from each $\overline b$. Then observe that these second edges are the same as the original edges.

Comment: I should have asked the question better.  I don't yet agree with the fact that there are $n$ edges emanating from $\overline{a}$.  And the my problem with that is symmetric in some sense.  What if there is $b\in B_{1}$ such that
$\chi(\phi_{j}(a)),\chi(\phi_{k}(a))\in\overline{b}$ for $j\neq k$?  This has to be ruled out somehow to guarantee $n$ distinct edges.  But I can't see how to do it.

Comment: Ok.  Got it!  It follows from the fact that $\phi_{j}$ and $\psi_{k}$ are additive in $j$ and $k$ respectively.